# Get output and return codes of multiple interdependent commands using subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

```
import subprocess
with open ("log.txt",'a') as log:
    output = subprocess.Popen("ech ;echo hello", shell=True, stdout=log, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    print output.wait() # prints  0
```

`ech` writes "/bin/sh: ech: command not found" into "log.txt". But the return code is 0 (SUCCESS) because the last command was successful. I want to get individual command return codes and not the return code of just the last command.

Also, assume that the commands are dependent - 
For example: `cd .. ; pwd` - They should not be split and run as two subprocess calls, because then `pwd` would not take into account the effect of `cd ..`

The example just above is only for clarification purposes. Please don't recommend solving it by using `cwd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do what I always recommend people do as the very first lines of any Bash script:

```
set -e (quite standard)
set -o pipefail (requires Bash 3 or later)
```

Then, whenever a command (or part of a pipeline) fails, the whole script will fail.  This will cure your problem by stopping as soon as `ech` is not found.

Comment: :-) that's even better than mine "&" :-) I agree too, it is not a real python issue.

Answer (score 0):

This look more a bash problem. If you used a wrong command as "ech" and then you continue with something else than subprocess will not know that.

What you can do easily is to concatenate your bash command by && this will lead to a 0 just in case all the commands got proper execution.

Subprocess itself is creating a different process and you will execute there whatever you introduced, so doing as suggested will lead to a 0 only in the good case.

Comment: You mean && not &.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it simply. If you use one single command shell to process all the commands, you will only get the concatenated output and the return value of the shell itself, which will be the return value of the last executed command.

On the other hand, if you use a dedicated subprocess per command, you will have to mimic a real shell and process specially every command that could change the environment like `cd`, `export` or variable assignation to allow the *dependencies* to be applied to the following commands

TL/DR: if you want to mimic a real shell, you will have to write a real shell...

Answer (score 0):

I think subprocess can not do what you want.
but for your question, your could use `echo $?' to get exit code.

```
cmds = ['ech;', 'echo heelo']
cmds_str = ' echo $?;'.join(cmds) # output 'ech echo $?;echo heelo'

with open ("log.txt",'a') as log:
    output = subprocess.Popen(cmds_str, shell=True, stdout=log, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    print output.wait()
```

your file will be:

```
/bin/sh: ech: command not found
127
heelo
```

the last command's retcode is the 0 in this example.